# Is there any way to check closed tab console error in Firebug?

Tags: jquery, ajax, firebug

I have the scenario where I make an AJAX request on tab close and I want to see the information about that request.

Is it possible using Firebug to check for errors caused by an AJAX request after the tab was closed?

Comment: is this tab an iframe?

Comment: No, it is normal HTML page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Firebug's activation model](https://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/Activation) is based on URLs following the [same-origin policy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy) and the data it displays is bound to the specific tab you're looking at - or more precisely the same document. So when you close the tab the information is gone.

Though there are two ways how to get the information about the request:

1. **Do not close the tab**

   Simply avoid closing the tab and make the request on another event on your page to debug it.
2. **Use the Browser Console**

   The browser internal console lists all messages and errors happening on all tabs, even after they are closed. To open this console press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd> or click the Firefox menu > *Developer* > *Browser Console*.